# qt background image is not showing

Tags: qt, background, background-image

I am having difficulty setting up a background image for the main window. I have managed to do it before but now it just won’t work.

i have searched the internet and the forums for a solution and they are what i have done before, so thats why i am asking for a little help.

i created a qt resource file and put the image in there.
i know the URL of the image is correct because the image shows in the .ui designer file when i put it in the stylesheet. but when i run the application it doesnt show the image. only a blank application.

the application is blank because i specifically created a test project to be sure there are no other interuptions.

i cleaned the stylesheet of the ui designer file and now i am trying to do it in the code itself (which i managed before succesfully)

the code is:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setStyleSheet("MainWindow {background-image:url(:/files/MainPic/Technology-Banner1.jpg)}");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

oke, so just to clarify:

i tried adding the stylesheet to the centralwidget QWidget that is allready by default in the .ui file
i tried doing the same to the mainwindow

and now i am trying through code (which i previously managed)

and i know the stylesheet code is valid because the image shows in the .ui file when i add it. So just to be completely sure, i copied the stylesheet line directly from the .ui file stylesheet properties.

i really hope you guys can help me

thnx!

Comment: Hi ! "i know the URL of the image is correct" .. I'm pretty sure that is not true. Pay attention that with Qt, you have your project folder and the build folder. Anyway, you can put an absolute path instead of a relative path for your image. You can also create a ressource file using aliases (It's probably the best !). Or you can adapt your relative path.

Comment: if the URL of the image is not correct, it would not show up in the ui designer. Also, i did add a qt resource file. thats how i import the image.

it shows up in the qt ui designer tool but when i build and run the application, its blank.

also, just to test, i deleted one character from the url in the designer .ui stylesheet and the image dissapears because the url is incorrect

Comment: As I told you, when you use the ui designer, you work in your project folder, in which you have a subfolder files/... right ? When you compile, the executable is by default in the build folder. In this folder, have you the same architecture ? (files/... ) I don't think so, that's why I told you it's probably a path problem. I encountered similar problem in the path and using aliases will avoid you some headaches ;)

Comment: i understand exactly what you are talking about and you are right. In the build folder where the actual .exe file is being build, there is no /files folder. So i added it and made the paths exactly the same. It still isn't working. Thnx for trying to help me out by the way, i apreciate it

Comment: also, if i am correct. The .qrc file is added so that when you compile, all the sources in the .qrc are compiled into the binary files that are build by compiling. So if the image shows up in the ui designer, it should compile the image into the exe.. which means that there shouldnt be any seperate resource files in the build folder

Comment: i Fixed the problem, i think it was an internal problem with the operating system or something. 

I reinstalled QT and it still didnt work, and then i decided to wipe windows 8.1 from my computer and i went back to windows 7. I took the same steps as i tried before and it worked on the first time. Still dont know exactly where the problem was tho